# value of getElementByID with blank spaces not working in xajax

Tags: php, xajax

I am writing the following code:

```
<?php
   require_once("xajax/xajax_core/xajaxAIO.inc.php");
   $xajax = new xajax();

   function testEE($datos){
      $x = $datos;
      $rr = new xajaxResponse();
      $rr->alert($x);
      return $rr;
   }
   
   $xajax->registerFunction("testEE");
   $xajax->processRequest();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Test E</title>
<?php $xajax->printJavascript("xajax/"); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="display" style="width:750px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; margin-top:100px;">
   <form id='forma' name='forma'>
      <table cellpadding='8' style='float:left;'>
         <tr><td>Pregunta:</td><td><textarea name='question1' id='question1' cols='40' rows='8'></textarea></td></tr>
         <tr><td colspan='2'><input type='button' value='Agregar' onclick="xajax_testEE(document.getElementById('question1').value)"></td></tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine if a put a single word in the textarea but if I try to put 2 or more words it does nothing

I have tried this:

```
<?php
   require_once("xajax/xajax_core/xajaxAIO.inc.php");
   $xajax = new xajax();

   function testEE($datos){
      $x = $datos;
      $rr = new xajaxResponse();
      $rr->alert($x);
      return $rr;
   }
   
   $xajax->registerFunction("testEE");
   $xajax->processRequest();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Test E</title>
<?php $xajax->printJavascript("xajax/"); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenido">
   <div id="display" style="width:750px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; margin-top:100px;">
      <form id='forma' name='forma'>
         <table cellpadding='8' style='float:left;'>
            <tr><td>Pregunta:</td><td><textarea name='question1' id='question1' cols='40' rows='8'></textarea></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Respuesta 1:</td><td><textarea name='respuesta1' id='respuesta1' cols='40' rows='8'></textarea></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan='2'><input type='button' value='Agregar' onclick="myFunction()"></td></tr>
         </table>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("question1").value;
  xajax_testEE(x)
  alert('myFunction alert': x)
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I enter a single word, I get the 2 alerts (as expected) but if I enter more than 1 word I only get the alert of myFunction with the complete string but I don't get the alert id the xajax function

Comment: Where is the definition of `xajax_testEE`?

Comment: with these 2 commands, xajax transforms testEE into xajax_testEE

Comment: I don't get a response from www.xajax-project.org. Is there a better link to the documentation?